# How do I use a system image with variable colour in MenuBarExtra?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to pass a variable along with my system image in MenuBarExtra, e.g.

```
MenuBarExtra("Show some cell bars", systemImage: "cellularbars")
```

But I can't figure out how to pass the variable itself. With a regular image I could do something like:

```
Image(systemName: "cellularbars", variableValue: 0.5)
```

But that doesn't appear to be part of the API for MenuBarExtra. I'm curious if there's a workaround. I looked into using Label but ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the [`init(content:label:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menubarextra/init(content:label:)) API

```
MenuBarExtra {
    Button("1"){}
    Button("2"){}
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "cellularbars", variableValue: 0.5)
}
```